# UIView animation on iOS - Subviews not resizing

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have a problem with animating UIView resize - it's subviews are not resizing at all. When i'm resizing it in Interface Builder(manually, by mouse), everything works well, but when i try to animate it like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f animations:^{
CGRect old = self.DescriptionView.frame;
old.size.height += 150;
self.DescriptionView.frame = old;
}];
```

Only UIView resizes, but all of the subviews remains the same .. I'd be very glad for any help, thanks in advance!

Mateusz Urban

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, but all of my constraints are good because of everything works fine, when i'm resizing it manually in Interface Builder